# Cannot apply multi background color to material ui snackbar

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, material-ui, snackbar

How to apply multi background color to material UI snackbar? I tried with linear-gradient as mentioned below but it doesn't work.

```
import Snackbar from 'material-ui/Snackbar';

const bodyStyle = {
  border: `2px solid ${config.actualWhite}`,
  minWidth: '50%',
  maxWidth: '100%',
  height:'55px',
  backgroundColor: 'linear-gradient(to right bottom, #00897B, #FFE082)',
  fontFamily: config.fontFamily,
  fontStyle: config.fontStyle,
  fontWeight: config.fontWeight,
  fontSize: config.fontSize
}

<Snackbar
   open={this.state.openLogout}
   message="You are Successfuly loggedout! Thanks for being part of web Family!"
   autoHideDuration={4000}
   bodyStyle={bodyStyle}
   action="Close"
   onRequestClose={this.handleRequestClose}
   onActionTouchTap={this.handleRequestClose}
   style={myTheme.snackbarfromTop}
/>
```

[Snackbar screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N6M9K.png)

Comment: Changing backgroundColor to background with linear-gradient color worked for me. Attached snackbar image for ref.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## material-ui v0

You've got a slight error in your CSS. Specifically, `backgroundColor` should be `background` because the `linear-gradient` function returns an image, not a color. So, you should have:

```
const bodyStyle = {
  border: `2px solid ${config.actualWhite}`,
  minWidth: '50%',
  maxWidth: '100%',
  height:'55px',
  // Note the change to background here
  background: 'linear-gradient(to right bottom, #00897B, #FFE082)',
  fontFamily: config.fontFamily,
  fontStyle: config.fontStyle,
  fontWeight: config.fontWeight,
  fontSize: config.fontSize
}
```

Note that you should consider making the switch to the v1-beta, which should be promoted to the [stable version sometime in early 2018](https://material-ui-next.com/discover-more/roadmap/#when-do-we-intend-to-release-stable-v1-). I describe the appropriate solution for that below.

## material-ui v1

Changing the `backgroundColor` of a `Snackbar` works but will have no visible effect because the entire `Snackbar` is filled by one of it's children, `SnackbarContent`, and that child has it's background [hardcoded in the source](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/v1-beta/src/Snackbar/SnackbarContent.js). By default, that backgroundColor is set to:

```
const backgroundColor = theme.palette.shades[reverseType].background.default;
```

So, what's happening is that your desired gradient background is being covered up by the child.

To fix this, you need to use the `SnackbarContentProps` described [in the `Snackbar` API](https://material-ui-next.com/api/snackbar/) to override the `backgroundColor` in the child:

```
const styles = theme => ({
  myCustomBackground: {
    background: 'linear-gradient(to right bottom, #00897B, #FFE082)',
  },
});

<Snackbar
  SnackbarContentProps={{
    className: classes.myCustomBackground,
  }}
/>
```

The `SnackbarContentProps` are spread down to the child (visible on [line 252 of the source](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/v1-beta/src/Snackbar/Snackbar.js) as of December 2017), so everything you put in that object will become a prop to the `SnackbarContent` child. Here, you're setting the child's `className` property to `myCustomBackground` so that it will display your desired gradient instead of the default.

Here are a couple of other points to note:

- I've left off all the other props and styling to keep the example as condensed as possible.
- Gradient backgrounds must be set with the `background` CSS attribute instead of the `backgroundColor` attribute because gradients are images, not colors.

Comment: Thanks for your time. I applied in a same way as you mentioned above but it doesn't work for me. I'm using material-ui version 0.18.7. But your answer helped me the other way. I changed backgroundColor to background with linear-gradient color in my bodyStyle. It is working perfectly fine now. Thanks

Comment: Oh alright, I hadn't realized you weren't using material-ui@next. Give me a minute to update my answer.

Comment: Also, you really should consider upgrading to the next version (v1-beta), which has many improvements (and breaking changes) compared to the current version.

Comment: Thank you:) Yes I have to update to use incredible improvements introduced in material-ui@next.